# Após escolher uma opção na selectbox, desabilitar e mudar o texto de duas outras selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Beleza galera. Tenho três selectbox e após escolher na primeira Select box a opção "Filmes", gostaria de desabilitar as outras duas selectbox e modificar seus textos para "N/A":

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria">
<option value="1">Animes</option>
<option value="2">Séries</option>
<option value="3">Filmes</option>
</select>

<select id="status" name="status">
<option value="1">Completa(o)</option>
<option value="2">Em exibição</option>
</select>

<select id="episodios" name="episodios">
<option value="02">02 Episódios</option>
<option value="03">03 Episódios</option>
<option value="04">04 Episódios</option>
<option value="05">....</option>
</select>
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: JS puro ou jQuery, ou tanto faz?

Comment: O mais simples. O site que estou fazendo é bem simples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode armazenar as `options` dos `selects` e depois restaurar com `onchange`:

```js
var status = $("#status").html();
var episodios = $("#episodios").html();
$("#categoria").on("change", function(){
   if($(this).val() == 3){
      $("#status, #episodios").html("<option value=''>N/A</option>");
   }else{
      $("#status").html(status);
      $("#episodios").html(episodios);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="categoria" name="categoria">
<option value="1">Animes</option>
<option value="2">Séries</option>
<option value="3">Filmes</option>
</select>

<select id="status" name="status">
<option value="1">Completa(o)</option>
<option value="2">Em exibição</option>
</select>

<select id="episodios" name="episodios">
<option value="02">02 Episódios</option>
<option value="03">03 Episódios</option>
<option value="04">04 Episódios</option>
<option value="05">....</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Funcionou 100%. Muito Obrigado

Comment: @MárcioFernandes Eu que agradeço! Obg!